# Value of selector is undefined in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<table class="list" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr class="dataRow">
    <td scope="row" class="dataCell">
      <a href="https://test.com/test" class="ng-binding">1</a>
    </td>
    <td scope="row" class="dataCell">
      <a href="https://test.com/test" class="ng-binding">2</a>
    </td>
    <td scope="row" class="dataCell">
      <a href="https://test.com/test" class="ng-binding">3</a>
    </td>    
    <td scope="row" class="dataCell">
      <a href="https://test.com/test" class="ng-binding">Homepage</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="dataRow">
    <td scope="row" class="dataCell">
      <a href="https://test.com/test" class="ng-binding">1</a>
    </td>
    <td scope="row" class="dataCell">
      <a href="https://test.com/test" class="ng-binding">2</a>
    </td>
    <td scope="row" class="dataCell">
      <a href="https://test.com/test" class="ng-binding">3</a>
    </td>
    <td scope="row" class="dataCell">
      <a href="https://test.com/test" class="ng-binding">Blog</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="dataRow">
    <td scope="row" class="dataCell">
      <a href="https://test.com/test" class="ng-binding">1</a>
    </td>
    <td scope="row" class="dataCell">
      <a href="https://test.com/test" class="ng-binding">2</a>
    </td>
    <td scope="row" class="dataCell">
      <a href="https://test.com/test" class="ng-binding">3</a>
    </td>  
    <td scope="row" class="dataCell">
      <a href="https://test.com/test" class="ng-binding">Contact</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


var tableRow = document.querySelectorAll('.dataRow');
var links = $('.dataCell:nth-child(4) .ng-binding');

for(var i=0; i<tableRow.length; i++){

  console.log(links[i]);
}
```

don't understand why the value of `links` is `undefined` 
I've tried having the links variable created inside the loop as well but I get the same result - I think its because links is not an array? if thats the case how would I do that?

I've added the markup to explain my question better...I'm trying to get links from the table cell and do a `.click()` on them

Comment: Why is your `for` loop using `tableRow.length`, but you're iterating `links`, not `tableRow`?  There is no guarentee that `tableRow.length` is the same value as `links.length`.

Comment: @charlietfl - yes, you can.  It is an array like object and works just fine with this type of `for` loop.  It iterates the DOM elements in the jQuery object.

Comment: Why aren't you using `$('.dataRow')`?

Comment: This looks like an XY problem in the first place seeing a class `ng-binding` which makes it part of angular app. What is this code going to be doing?

Comment: im using `$('.dataRow')` to findout how many rows there are - i need to do a callback on each `links` found in the `.dataRow`

Comment: is that `ng-binding` not angular? Shouldn't need this code if it is. Also you need to provide a proper explanation of what exactly you are attempting to do.

Comment: yes it is, im using the .ng-binding class name to select the elements

Comment: you should be using a directive for whatever it is you are trying to do with `callback` which still isn't clear what that objective is

Comment: the code im dealing with happens to be written in angular  - but what I'm trying to do, does not require angular

Answer (score -3):

**This is the jQuery solution, but if that is a angular app you should use directives**

> var links = $('.dataCell:nth-child(4) .ng-binding');

This object length will be 0. See how nth-child works https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

I guess you want to click on last links in each cell.

```
var dataRow = $('.dataRow');
dataRow.each(function(ind, elem){
    console.log($(this).find('.ng-binding').eq(3));
    $(this).find('.ng-binding').eq(3).click();
});
```

Comment: how can you rewrite it when you don't even know what the intent is with the loop of the rows? Also `get()` does not return jQuery. `get()` and `[index]` do the same thing

Comment: I know but jQuery standard requires to use get()

Comment: no it doesn't , it is a convenience method. My comments were made when your answer was incorrect before you edited it

Comment: I know the difference between `get()` and `eq()` and that is a  inattention mistake. so never mind. In jquery doc says that you should use `get()` if you want to get element.